# Css equivalent of :has()

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent

In the following example:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row"> <!-- bottom margin here needs to be 0 -->
    <div class="section">
      <div class="row">...</div>
      <div class="row">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.row {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

If div .row is parent of div .section reset bottom margin to 0.

I can do this with JQuery, but is there a way to do it in CSS?

Comment: No, CSS does not have parent selectors.

Comment: Just to clarify, the bottom margin of the div you point to actually adds space to the very bottom of your block of divs. That's the space you want to eliminate?

Comment: Why not use something like `.row:last-child {  margin-bottom:0px;}` CSS can't go up, only down, hence the `cascading` part.

Comment: @Nick R: The term "cascading" refers to something else entirely. Nothing to do with parent -> child.

Answer (score 19):

At the moment there is no way in CSS to select the parent element of another element.

However, in CSS4 there is the `:has` pseudo-class - [http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/ :has](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational)

> the following selector matches only `<a>` elements that contain an `<img>`
> child:
>
> ```
> a:has(> img)
> ```
>
> The following selector matches a `<dt>` element immediately followed by
> another `<dt>` element:
>
> ```
> dt:has(+ dt)
> ```
>
> The following selector matches `<section>` elements that don’t contain
> any heading elements:
>
> ```
> section:not(:has(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6))
> ```
>
> Note that ordering matters in the above selector. Swapping the nesting
> of the two pseudo-classes, like:
>
> ```
> section:has(:not(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6))
> ```
>
> ...would result matching any `<section>` element which contains anything
> that’s not a header element.

It looks like you may be using a recursive function to generate your sections/rows. Perhaps add a class to the row if it has sub-sections? Then you could target that class to apply margin-bottom to.

Comment: You are conflating CSS selectors with CSS. It's still undecided if the `:has()` selector will be available in CSS. See the section on fast/complete profiles in the document you link to.

Comment: `:has()` is still not supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Just a sidenote. CSS4 doesn't exist, and never will. It's just regular CSS with selectors level 4 :) – https://css-tricks.com/css4/

Answer (score 11):

You could do this by applying a negative `margin` to the `.section` element that's equivalent to the standard `margin` of `.row` element.

```
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row > .section {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Not valid in all situations