# How to apply css style when a span does not exists in a link?

Tags: css

I have the following `CSS` style that applies `padding-right` and changes the `font-size` on a span that is found inside of an `a` tag.

But, for other links that do not have a `span` inside of them, I want to apply `padding-right: 1.35rem;` to keep the links virtually lined up.

Here is my CSS code that adds the `padding-right`

```
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a > span {
    padding-right: 0.50rem;
     font-size: .85rem;
 }
```

How can I apply `CSS` code only when the span does not exist inside of the `a` tag?

Comment: using `:has()` [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/3654837)

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `:has()` does not exist in CSS. I'ts merely a proposal. It is [not supported by a single browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility). OP, what you're requesting can't really be done in CSS, as the "C" in "CSS" stands for *cascading*. It can only traverse downwards, not upwards. By that logic, once you go downwards to the `<span>` level to check its existence, you can't apply style *back upwards* to the parent. You'll have to use a JavaScript workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) **,** [CSS equivalent of :has()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037763/css-equivalent-of-has) **,** [CSS selector - element with a given child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child)

Answer (score 0):

Unless `:has()` is launched.

The best I could think of is by writing the default setting in a before you specify to span. For example:

```
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a{
    padding-right: 0;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

See snippet for some demo:

```css
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a > span {
    padding-right: 0.50rem;
    font-size: .85rem;
}
 
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a{
    padding-right: 0;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
 <div class="sidebar-menu">
  <div class="sidebar-dropdown">
   <div class="sidebar-submenu">
    
    <!-- li a with span -->
    <li>
     <a>
      <span>
       test
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <!-- li a without span -->
    <li>
     <a>
     test
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a>
     test
     </a>
    </li>  
    <!-- li a with span -->
    <li>
     <a>
      <span>
       test
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the `<span>` and add an `id=` to the anchors that should require a different amount for the `padding-right` style.

```
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a {
    padding-right: 0.50rem;
    font-size: .85rem;
 }

#chgpadding {
    padding-right: 1.40rem;
}
```

Your related html would be `<a href="" id="chgpadding"></a>` instead of `<a href=""><span></span></a>`. Since you only have one element featured in the `#chgpadding` style, CSS will (by default) give it precidence over the `...li a` (parent) style.