# How to invert color of entire page when hovering on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I would like to invert the colors of the entire page (text, images, background) when hovering on a specific link in my menu. Think about it like a Dark Mode preview just by hovering on a button.

I'm aware of the css filter: invert(100%); but not sure how to make the entire page invert based on one hover using CSS. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `<body style="filter: invert(1);">` add this style-sheet in your body tag via JS, while hovering the link

Comment: You might be interested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037763/css-equivalent-of-has, 

AFIAK it's not possible using a CSS only solution, but may be soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Javascript to achieve what you want.
The idea is to apply a class with `filter: invert(1);` to the body element when the mouse is over (`onmouseoover` event) the link and remove it when the mouse leaves (`onmouseleave` event):

```js
const invertLink = document.querySelector('#invert');
const toggleDark = () => document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('dark');
invertLink.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleDark);
invertLink.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleDark);
```

```css
.dark {
  filter: invert(1);
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <a href="#" id="invert">Hover me!</a><br><br>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/">
</body>
```