# how to make a css rule only apply when a certain div id is on the page

Tags: css

How do I conditionally apply a `@media print` css ruleset ONLY when a certain div is present on the page.

I have the following css which helps when printing `#mytargetdiv`:

```
@media print {
    .inside-article > :not(#mytargetdiv), .inside-navigation, .site-footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It works great, except that some pages have `#mytargetdiv` and some do not contain a div with that id.  If a div with the id `#mytargetdiv` is NOT present on the given page, then I do not want to apply this `@media print` rule.

How do I exclude this `@media print` css rule on pages that do not contain `#mytargetdiv`.

Comment: hi, will the rule apply to descendants/siblings of the target div? this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037763/css-equivalent-of-has/29037846

Comment: You will have to detect that with javascript then perhaps add a class to the body to signify that. You cannot do this with css alone

Answer (score 1):

You can check for existence of the id using Javascript, then add the styling if it is found.

```js
if (document.getElementById('mytargetdiv') != null) {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '@media print { .inside-article > :not(#mytargetdiv), .inside-navigation, .site-footer { display: none; } }';
    document.body.appendChild(style);
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Too bad .css alone can't handle this.  Using the logic you're showing with javascript, I guess in my php code I could conditionally insert the style tag only on the pages that require it (i.e. those that I know will contain #mytargetdiv).

Comment: I was able to get it to work by conditionally inserting the @media print style rule via php only on pages that I know contain #mytargetdiv.